# Type mismtach using method of raw type in Java

Tags: java, generics

Here are several questions related to type mismatch using generics in Java, but I was not able to find anything corresponding to my case.

I wonder why this error happens in below code?

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

in line

> for (String element : arg.someMethod())

But if

```
SomeInterface arg
```

is changed to

```
SomeInterface<?> arg
```

it works. Why list parameter type is erased if it is not connected to interface type parameter?

```
import java.util.List;

public class TypeMismatchExample
{
    interface SomeInterface<P extends Object>
    {
        P someParametrizedMethod();

        List<String> someMethod();
    }

    void example(SomeInterface arg)
    {
        for (String element : arg.someMethod())
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a raw type in your code, **all** generic type information in that class is lost -- thus, the compiler does not know that `someMethod` returns a `List` of type `String`.

The relevant portion of the JLS: [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from
>   its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds
>   to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to
>   C.

So since you declared the method parameter as `SomeInterface`, which is a raw type, you cannot take advantage of the generic `someMethod`, even though its generic type parameter is not the same as `P`.